# Dynamics 365 on premise First request creation takes longer time

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've been two days struggling to know the reason but with no luck

I have dynamics 365 on premise and we have some customizations on case form and workflows and plugins on create

When I open new fresh session the request creation took almost 8 seconds , however after save first request and try to submit a new request again it took almost 2 seconds

I need to understand what's the caching behavior on server side that make first request took all this time compared to the upcoming requests  coz this is misleading to decide performance is good or not

Thank you,